# Meaning of question mark operator '?' before arguments in Haxe

Tags: haxe

What is the difference between these two function signatures?

```
function f(?i:Int = 0) {}
function f(i:Int = 0) {}
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference whether argument is prefixed with `?`, both compile fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is indeed no reason to use `?` in this example, but there is a difference.

On a [statically typed target](https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/compiler-targets.html), `f(null)` would not compile since the basic types `Int`, `Float` and `Bool` are not [nullable](https://haxe.org/manual/types-nullability.html) there. However, the `?` [implies nullability](http://haxe.org/manual/types-function-optional-arguments.html), meaning that

```
function f(?i:Int)
```

is actually the same as

```
function f(i:Null<Int> = null)
```

As you can see, the `?` has two effects:

- A `null` [default value](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function-default-values.html) is added, so you can omit `i` during the call: `f();`
- The type is wrapped in [`Null<T>`](https://api.haxe.org/Null.html?). While this makes no difference on dynamic targets, it usually has a runtime performance cost on static targets (again: *only* for `Int` / `Float` / `Bool` arguments).

The only reason I can think of why you would want arguments with basic types to be nullable is to enable *optional argument skipping*. When calling `f` in this example, `i` can only be skipped if it is nullable:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        f("Test"); // 0, "Test"
    }

    static function f(?i:Int = 0, s:String) {
        trace(i, s);
    }
}
```

---

Note that if you add a [default value](http://haxe.org/manual/types-function-default-values.html) to an optional argument, that value will be used even if you explicitly pass `null`:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        f(); // 0
        f(null); // 0
    }

    static function f(?i:Int = 0) {
        trace(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are two different things. A ? Means an optional parameter. So if can be completely excluded from the function call and no substitution will take place.

(x:Float = 12) is a default parameter. Meaning if its excluded from the function call the value of 12 will be used.

Comment: While you are not wrong, default parameters imply that they are optional. From a caller's perspective, they do not need to be entered. Since most languages that haxe compiles to do not support this, then an optional parameter is pretty much the same as a default parameter: the default value should be in the comments.

This is not a critic of your statement, only an opinion on what is missing.

Comment: This answer implies that the default value of `12` would be inserted at the call-site if omitted from the call. As the JS Source tab here shows, that is _not_ the case: https://try.haxe.org/#De82a