# Optional arguments without ? identifier

Tags: nullable, haxe

In the Haxe 3 manual at http://haxe.org/manual/types-function-default-values.html, we have `static function test(?i = 12, s = "bar")`.

Why isn't it `static function test(?i = 12, ?s = "bar")` or `static function test(i = 12, s = "bar")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of question mark operator '?' before arguments in Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914614/meaning-of-question-mark-operator-before-arguments-in-haxe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there's a subtle difference between `?i=1` and `i=1`:

- `function test(?i=1):String` is of type `Null<Int> -> String`
- `function test(i=1):String` is of type `Int -> String`

While `?i` indicates an optional argument – and that always implies nullability – `i=1` indicates a default value and should eliminate the need for a `Null<T>` box.

See [Optional Arguments and Nullability](http://haxe.org/manual/types-nullability-optional-arguments.html) and an [example](http://try.haxe.org/#4cA40).